# validate number of given letters in a word (duplicates and order doesn't matter much)

Tags: java, regex, validation, match

I need to validate if a word meets a minimum letter requirement and I am stuck on duplicates.

For example: I need my word to contain the following letters `AAAABBC` (at least 4 times `A`, at least 2 times `B`, and at least one time `D`).

This should match:

- `ABRACADABRA`;
- `BRACADABRAA`;
- `BRAACADABRAA`;
- `DBRAACADABRAA`;

and so on.

I managed to build this regex: `A.*(?=(A.*){4})`, but I don't know how to enforce the rest of the letters and minimum occurrences. I thought about something like this: `(A.*(?=(A.*){4,})|B.*(?=(B.*){2,}))` but this only gives me the guarantee that the word has at least 4 `A`s or at least 2 `B`s. Again, there is no guarantee on the letters in the word, I only need to make sure the letters I am asking are there and they appear at least the number of times I request.

So, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
^(?=(?:[^A]*A){4})(?=(?:[^B]*B){2})(?=[^D]*D).+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU4sI0/1)